# Unzip with apache ant

Tags: apache, ant, zip, tar, unzip

I have a folder with some .zip files, and each of it has the same file names. It is possible to unzip them all with apache ant, edit some particular file and to zip it back? Tried to unzip like this

```
<unzip dest = "temp">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/libs">
        <include name="*.prpt" />
    </fileset>
</unzip>
```

The problem is that i can't reference a file from fileset, additional it overrides each other.

Comment: Do you have *.prpt files in ${basedir}/bmo directory

Comment: yes... .prpt it's a zip-like archive

Comment: what is it? .prpt file? I think ant unzip task can really unzip only these file types - zip,war and jar. Can you try changing the file extension and try?

Comment: i tried to unzip a .prpt file... it's working... doesn't matter... give me a hint how to do this with .zip files.

Comment: I couldn't understand it clearly  - 'The problem is that i can't reference a file from fileset, additional it overrides each other.'

Comment: Did you check this out - http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html

Comment: i tried to unzip each archive in it's own folder... something like <unzip dest = "temp/${fileFromFileset}"> and to edit in each of this folder the files.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what you expect, because your question is slightly confusing, I am guessing it.

```
<target name="find.zips">
<foreach target="unpack.zip" param="foreach.zip" inheritall="true">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*.prpt"/>
</foreach>
</target>
<target name="unpack.zip">
  <script language="javascript">
           <![CDATA[
               name = project.getProperty("foreach.zip");
               index = name.lastIndexOf(".prpt");
               zipname = name.substring(index+1);
               project.setProperty("foreach.zipname",zipname);
          ]]>
       </script>
  <unzip src="${foreach.zip}" dest="tmp/zipsrc/${foreach.zipname}/"/>
</target>
```

hope it helps. cheers.